# Does the PowerShell Active Directory call System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement

Tags: .net, powershell, active-directory

Does anyone know if the Microsoft PowerShell Active Directory module calls the System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement .Net namespace? Or if Microsoft have open sourced the module so that I can look myself.

I'm trying to draw out a stack topology and suddenly realised that I don't really know what cmdlets such as Get-ADUser and New-ADUser do internally and what if anything they call (i.e. how abstracted they are).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not exactly the same, but very similar.

[`Get-ADUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser?view=win10-ps) for example, returns a [`Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.activedirectory.management.aduser?view=activedirectory-management-10.0) object. Compare that to [`UserPrincipal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal?view=netframework-4.7.2) and you'll see they're different, not only in the namespace, but in the properties, etc. However there is still a lot of abstraction going on, and thus overhead.

If you're worried about performance, you can always just use .NET's `DirectoryEntry` from PowerShell. There are actually [type accelerators](https://www.jaapbrasser.com/working-with-type-accelerators-in-powershell/) just for `DirectoryEntry` and `DirectorySearcher`.

```
([adsisearcher]'samaccountname=jaap').FindOne()            #DirectorySearcher
[adsi]'LDAP://CN=Jaap,OU=AdminUsers,DC=JaapBrasser,DC=Com' #DirectoryEntry
```

Comment: I wasn't concerned with performance, but good point and nice blog post! I was concerned with if writing 2 sets of tools, one set in a web api form and another in .ps1 scripts form (for difference audiences) then it would be nice to at least know if they do the same calls or not. I guess I could call ps1 scripts from a web api somehow, but that seems really weird and I just don't want to go there.

Comment: You can run PowerShell from .NET, but I've done it and it's a pain. You're better off going the other way: use the .NET classes from PowerShell, which isn't that hard. Everything in .NET is available in PowerShell. This is a quick overview of how to do that: https://4sysops.com/wiki/useful-net-classes-for-powershell/